# How do I locate a UILabel in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

I am working on someone else's project and I can't for the life of me find where the text "Frame2" is used.  I ran the simulator and the debugger spit out this:

```
Printing description of $147:

<UILabel: 0x7f7ff655a260; frame = (0 3.5; 105 21.5); text = 'Frame2'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7f7ff65586a0>
```

Can that printout reveal the location?

Comment: What do you mean by "location"?

Comment: Cmd-shift-f and search for "Frame2" should show you the file where that string is assigned, no?

Comment: you can find the occurrences of .text or setText in your project and put breakpoints in the class that console logged this message OR check the NSLOg and see where the label is logging.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a symbolic breakpoint for `setTitle` on UILabel and trace where it gets called. You can follow this link for instructions on how to do that: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/xcode-breakpoint-wizardry/

Answer (score 0):

I think we should assume that this text is set in the storyboard. The simple way to deal with this is to open the storyboard *as text*. It is a simple XML file, and you will then easily be able to search it and find the text "Frame2".